# Error Integrating Braintree Dropin In a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, braintree, venmo

I need help with Android Integration inside a fragment , It is working fine when the code is implemented in an Activity but in My Case , i need to implement it in a Fragment .

I am trying to call the dropin ui from a Fragment but unable to do so.

Steps i followed :-
1) I fetched the braintree token using get_braintree_token(rootview.getContext()) .

2) After getting token i passed it to onBraintreeSubmit(braintreeToken ,viewb)
3) When it reaches startActivityForResult() in onBraintreeSubmit function ,The BrainTree UI is not inflated .It directly moves to onActivityResult() with resultcode 1 and some random Request code .
I have written my functions Below.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup   container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
get_braintree_token(rootview.getContext());
return rootview;
  }
public void get_braintree_token(final Context viewb)
{

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "My    server URL",    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String     response) {

                    braintreeToken = response.toString();
                    Log.e("Braintreetoken","token is:"+braintreeToken);

                    onBraintreeSubmit(braintreeToken, viewb);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            braintreeToken = null;
        }
    });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}


public void onBraintreeSubmit(String token, Context c) {
    Log.e("tokenreceived",token);
    DropInRequest dropInRequest = new  DropInRequest();

    dropInRequest.clientToken(token);
    Intent drop = dropInRequest.getIntent(c);
    startActivityForResult(drop, BRAINTREE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == BRAINTREE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == 1) {
            DropInResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
            // use the result to update your UI and send the payment method nonce to your server
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // the user canceled
        } else {
            // handle errors here, an exception may be available in
            Exception error = (Exception) data.getSerializableExtra(DropInActivity.EXTRA_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you fix this issue???

Comment: No , This issue is not yet Fixed

Comment: am also fasing the issues if am selection creditcard AddCardDetails Activity Opened.If am selection PayPal how can i handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Token value , Here a Json Response is being passed , which is Creating the Issue so extract token from response and pass it to braintree method instead of passing the json response.